WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path
Running a pod in AWS EKS using the WebIdentityTokenCredentials (which the service account provides) only works, if the STS module of the SDK is in the classpath.
Java version 2 -
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.29</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.29</version>
</dependency>

I know there is no need mention version explicitly but I tried adding in every possible way but still not able to resolve the error.
Still getting error :  WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path. Also, pods are not able to up as on the startup of the application AWS SQS Bean is required.
AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withConnectionTimeout(5000))
                    .withRegion(region)
                    .build();

Also, I have tried mentioning this also but still no luck.
withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())

